# What is the optimal way to exploit Docker multi-stage builds?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm using multi-stage builds in my `Dockerfile` (the first stage is a BUILD, and the second is the RUN).

I want to know if I should, in my second stage, copy the `node_modules` folder or if I should run an  `npm i`. What is the optimal way ?

**Note**: All the `apk` packages that I install in the first stage are required to run `npm ci` properly (I had many errors : `node-gyp`, etc)

```
# Build container stage
FROM node:alpine AS BUILD_IMAGE

RUN apk --no-cache add -u --virtual build-dependencies \
    g++ gcc libgcc libstdc++ linux-headers make python3
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci && npm clean cache --force && apk del build-dependencies
COPY . .
RUN npm run lint
RUN npm run tsc
RUN npm prune --production

# Run container stage
FROM node:alpine AS app
WORKDIR /app
COPY /package*.json ./
# Should I copy the `node_modules` folder or
# should I run an `npm i` ? What is the optimal method?
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/node_modules ./node_modules
# Clean dev packages
EXPOSE 8080
# Run the container with a non-root User
USER node
CMD [ "node", "dist/src/app.js" ]
```

Comment: The NodeJS website recommends running npm install rather than copying the whole node_modules folder. From the docs:

Note that, rather than copying the entire working directory, we are only copying the package.json file. This allows us to take advantage of cached Docker layers. bitJudo has a good explanation of this here. Furthermore, the npm ci command, specified in the comments, helps provide faster, reliable, reproducible builds for production environments. You can read more about this here.

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: @TommyBs: This article http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/ is mentioned in the Node.js docs suggests copying `node_modules`. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I always run npm install (ci) inside of the docker when I want to build the image, because if you copy node_modules from dev environment to docker image, depend on you OS you use for developing, many of the binary files inside  node_modules are wrong ( Windows/mac => Linux ) also if you use ubuntu and your image is based on Alpine again you will have some problem.

The best option is always to make a layer just for node_modules build and after that, make an application layer based on your node_module layer => you will use cache and faster build.
Note: if you wanna copy node_modules on Windows use WSL2 (Ubuntu) and also build your images based on Ubuntu(Debian) then you don't worry about errors

Comment: I'm not copying `node_modules` from my local machine. I'm copying them from the build stage layer. Look at this example mentioned in the Nodejs docs : http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/